# React | Single onchange method for multiple dynamic select box

Tags: reactjs, select, react-redux

I'm getting response from API like below `json`. By using that response I'm generating dynamic `select`.

**Issue:**
Not able to select different value for different selectbox. I'm trying to achieve with state. How to declare state dynamically in this case.

**JSON**

```
const jsonFields = {
  fields: [
    { name: "sex", value: ["m", "f"] },
    { name: "age", value: ["10", "20"] }
  ]
};
```

*note: I don't know json key name like sex and age. name will be dynamic*

**Select Change:**

```
handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };
```

**Loading fields:**

```
loadfields = () => {
    const FieldsArray = [];
    let FieldsData = jsonFields.fields;
    FieldsData.forEach((val, index) => {
      let FieldsDatavalue = val.value;
      FieldsArray.push(
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="controlled-open-select">{val.name}</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value=""
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age"
            }}
          >
            {FieldsDatavalue.map(option => (
              <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      );
    });
    return FieldsArray;
  };
```

Scenario : [**Code Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mo5o1wwzqy)

Comment: Question is already answered >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349628/how-to-make-dynamic-state-for-multiple-fields-in-react/54571694#54571694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not storing the selected value in your state, and the `name` in `inputProps` is hard coded to `'age'`. If you fix those problems, it works:

```
      <Select
        value={this.state[val.name] ? this.state[val.name] : ''}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        inputProps={{name: val.name}}
      >
```

Here's a [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3v4vrmr8w).

UPDATE: The undefined values cause the label to overlap with the selected value, and since you retrieve them dynamically and cannot initialize them in the state, you can use a conditional `this.state[val.name] ? this.state[val.name] : ''` to fix the labels. (sandbox has been updated)

Comment: you beat me by a margin of some seconds :(

Comment: @MariaJeysinghAnbu Read this answer again and make sure you make **all** the suggested changes.

Comment: Thank you @Oblosys. I missed `InputProps` changes

Comment: @Vishal Sorry about that :-)