# How to make dynamic state for multiple fields in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
class Bills extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        productName: '',
        price: 0,
        quantity: 0,
        noOfProductsField: 0
    }
}
handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value,
    });
};

createFields = () => {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        let children = []
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.noOfProductsField; i++) {
            children.push(
                <div>
                    <Select
                        className={classes.textField}
                         value = { this.state[i] }
                    onChange={this.handleChange('productName')}
                        displayEmpty
                        SelectProps={{
                            MenuProps: {
                                className: classes.menu,
                            }
                        }}>
                        <MenuItem value="" disabled>
                            Select Product
                           </MenuItem>
                        {this.state.products.map((option, ind) => (
                            <MenuItem key={ind} value={option.productName}>
                                {option.productName}
                            </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                    </Select>
                    <TextField className={classes.textField} placeholder='Price' type='number' onChange={this.handleChange('price')} />
                    <TextField className={classes.textField} placeholder='Quantity' type='number' onChange={this.handleChange('quantity')} />
                </div>
            )
        }
        return children
    }
}
```

I Have this function which is creating 3 input fields in for loop

- productName
- price
- quantity

For Example if loop is running 2 times it will create 6 fields like image below:

[image: Click on this to see image]

So now i want to manage state for all 6 fields differently 
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create dynamic form inputs right? So what you can do is you can pass the name of the product to you handler `this.handleChange('productName')` and then you can do something like following. In your case you will need to use computed property name so as to dynamically set the state(like you are already doing)

```
handleChange = name => event => {
    //more logic here as per the requirement
    this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value,
    });
};
```

Or you can create seperate onChange handlers each for product, price, quantity.

```
handleProductChange = (name) => (evt) => {
    const newProducts = this.state.products.map((product, pidx) => {
      if (name !== product.productName) return product;
      return { ...product, productName: evt.target.value };
    });

    this.setState({ products: newProducts });
}
```

**Quick flow:** When product onChange occurrs you can store the product in the procucts array(in state) and when price change will occure you can send the product name along with it and map the product with price and quantity.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/kuyopus/1/edit?js,console,output) you can find a nice JS bin replica with React, of exact same thing you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for helping it just works correctly. if you liked my question, can you upvote it? Thank You

Comment: Glad you got it working. Sure, It was a good question. Welcome

Answer (score 2):

You can add `name` attribute to each input component and make one handler method which get the name as an argument.

```
handleInputChange(event) {

  const value = event.target.value;
  const name = event.target.name;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

You can read more about [how to handle multiple inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) on React docs.

Comment: Can we achieve the same goal with react hooks?

Comment: @DularaMalindu yes, but you need to use `spread operator` to merge the properties, because unlike `this.setState()` of class component, the `useState()` hook doesn't merge them. 
you can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

Answer (score 2):

you can create dynamic select field using react js

```
**Code sample:**

const templates = [
    {'id': 1, 'value': 'JavaScript', 'name': 'JavaScript'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'value': 'React', 'name': 'React'},    
    {'id': 3, 'value': 'Angular', 'name': 'Angular'},
    {'id': 4, 'value': 'Node', 'name': 'Node'},
    {'id': 5, 'value': 'Vue', 'name': 'Vue'},
 ]

class Dynamic extends React.Component {
  state={
    selectedTemplates: ""
  }

 onChange = (e) => {
   console.log(e)
   // selected value store into state
    this.setState({ 
      selectedTemplates: e.target.value 
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Dynamic Select(Options):</h2>
        <select className="form-control"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e.target.value)}
          >
          {
              templates.map(msgTemplate => {
                  return (
                      <option 
                        key={msgTemplate.id} 
                        name={msgTemplate.name} 
                        value={msgTemplate.text}
                       >
                          {msgTemplate.name}
                      </option>
                  )
              })
          }
       </select>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Dynamic />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

demo >> [codepen](https://codepen.io/MuhammadRizwan/pen/gqXZWo?editors=0011)

Answer (score 1):

Simple example for the state variables looks like:

```
this.state = {
test: 'hello'
}
```

you can **get the state values** dynamically by

```
let field_name = 'test';
let data = this.state[field_name];
```

you can **set the state or replace the state** like

```
let field_name = 'test';
this.setState({[field_name]: 'new'}) // test: 'new'
```

**complex state** replace like

```
let field_names = {key: 'test'}
this.setState({[field_name.key]: 'ok'}) // test: 'ok'
console.log(this.state[field_name.key]) // test: 'ok'
```

You can also use the **Template literals** like

```
this.setState({`${field_name.key}`: 'ok'}) // test: 'ok'
console.log(this.state[`${field_name.key}`]) // test: 'ok'
```

Superb, you got the solution.